# How many points were required to define a face in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: geometry

Consider a solid object in $\mathbb{R}^n$. How many points were required to define a face of the object, i.e. it's boundary, in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Do you mean a plane?

Comment: @PC1 I think the intention was $\partial \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the boundary. or the highest dimension facet of that object, except the object itself.